# Put images side by side

Tags: vb.net, image, jpeg

How do I combine two images in VB.net to create one big image. They are both 1920x1080 jpegs and I'd like it to come out in a 3840x1080 jpeg.

Like this: I get these images in:
image 1

[image]

And get this out: image 1 side by side with image 2

[image]

Comment: Give it a try, post a question when you get stuck.

Comment: `GDI+` and the `DrawImage` method will work. You need 2 `Rectangles` the `DrawImage` method takes a rectangle parameter. Create the Rectangles side to side then paint the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. The code is pretty easy, basically two images in one image out.

```
        Dim ImageOne As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile("img1")
    Dim ImageTwo As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("img2")
    'replace path of image two with Image2.ImageUrl
    Dim NewImageHeight As Integer = If(ImageOne.Height > ImageTwo.Height, ImageOne.Height, ImageTwo.Height)
    'To calculate height of new image
    Dim NewImageWidth As Integer = ImageOne.Width + ImageTwo.Width
    ' width of new image



    Dim NewImageBmp As New Bitmap(NewImageWidth, NewImageHeight, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    ' you can change the bpp as per your requirment. Size of image directly propotionate to bpp of image

    Dim NewImageGrx As Graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(NewImageBmp)


    NewImageGrx.DrawImageUnscaled(ImageOne, 0, 0)
    'draw first image at coordinate 0,0 
    NewImageGrx.DrawImageUnscaled(ImageTwo, ImageOne.Width, 0)
    'draw second image at coordinate image1.width,0
    Dim CombineImage As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg"
    NewImageBmp.Save("output file", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    ' saving combined image. You can specify the ImageFormat as per your requirment.

    'disposing objects after use
    ImageOne.Dispose()
    ImageTwo.Dispose()


    NewImageBmp.Dispose()
    NewImageGrx.Dispose()
```

Comment: _"The code is pretty easy"_ So, all you had to was **try something**? Do some research (read manual, check Google for tutorials, etc)? That's it and you got a working solution? And here we were thinking you were too lazy to write the code yourself... I'll upvote the effort to answer your own question but my close vote still stands...